# Google reCaptcha is not working on UIWebView on iOS 10 only

Tags: swift, recaptcha, ios10

I have integrated `UIWebView` in my `iOS` app. And I am loading `URL` which contain `google recaptcha` version 3.

I am able to see the Checkbox of recaptcha, but when I tap on checkbox to enable, it doesn't show images to verify on `iOS 10`.

This is occur only on iOS 10. On iOS 9,11,12 captcha is working using `UIWebView`.

Any pointer on this?

Comment: try using WKWebView

Comment: Currently app is heavily coupled with UIWebView. So we need solution with UIWebView